# mssql and nodejs, insert statement with values as object

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I need to make an insert query in `mssql` but I can't come around how to parse the values that come from an object to the query. I have this so far. I'm using a string builder, I put what the outcome of query is in the commented part

```
form = {x:'value1', y:'value2', z:'value3'}

return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
        var query = calculation.insert(form).toQuery();
        //query.text value will be: 'INSERT INTO [table] ([x], [y], [z]) VALUES (@1, @2, @3)'
        //query.values will be ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']

        new sql.Request().input('values', sql.VarChar, query.values).query(query.text).then(result => {
            return { completed: true }
        }).catch(err => {
            throw err;
            { completed: false };
        }) 
    }
)
```

But this is not working. I can't figure how to parse the query.values properly to the query. Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: How are you passing these values, in url?

Comment: it comes from the response (in express)

Comment: So you want the values to be picked from response and placed in your query string?

Comment: that's correct sir